# How to make Java process to use multiple CPU cores

Tags: java, cpu

Java process is not utilizing the more CPU cores during high load.
On an average java process uses 200% (i.e. 2 core) of CPU during high load and some time it reaches to 400% for very less time.
We have around 28 cores are available in the linux (OS) environment. 
I would like to know is there any way to make our process to use more CPU cores ?

Comment: More Threads will use more cores.

Comment: What does your application do? As Scary Wombat mentioned, you cannot spread the load across more CPU's than the number of Threads that your application uses to perform the processing. It looks like all the work is done by 2 threads, and sometimes 4 threads, at most.

Answer (score 2):

Your JVM and the host OS decide how many 'native' threads to use, and how those threads are mapped to physical processors based on task in hand.

So basically scheduling is up to the OS you can see what's going on.

From programming point of view you can check:

```
ForkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(X);
and
ExecutorService ex = Executors.neWorkStealingPool(X);
```